# Postfix Send many messages in one connection

Tags: postfix

i have a question about postfix.
We cand send to our providers smarthost 4000 Mails per Hour.

When we send this messages, we got the failure too many connections back.
Now i want to send all theese messages in one connection.

So my question: Is it possible to send 500 Mails simultaneously in one connection to the providers smarthost?

Best regards,
Andreas

Comment: Looks like you want SMTP connection caching. See http://www.postfix.org/CONNECTION_CACHE_README.html.

Answer (score 5):

With Postfix 2.2 or later, SMTP connection caching "on demand" is enabled by default, where connections will be reused "when a destination has a high volume of mail in the active queue" (what counts as "high volume" isn't discussed).

If you have a limited list of destinations which you want to keep connections open for (as per your smarthost situation) you can tell Postfix to really, really keep connections open:

```
smtp_connection_cache_destinations = $relayhost
```

If your relayhost uses TLS, you're out of luck, though, because "The Postfix shared connection cache cannot be used with TLS".